# Select Text-Align Center won't work Safari 11

Tags: html, css, safari

I can't get the text to be centered inside a select input , I've tried everything there's to try, including **-webkit-center**. I also tried to calculate padding so it looks centered, but it looks really bad,

Safari 11 just completely ignores **text-align:center** or **text-align:-webkit-center**

Comment: Web-browsers are free to render input elements like `<input />` and `<select>` as they wish, they are not required to apply all CSS rules to them as though they were normal elements.

Comment: That said, you'll want to look at `-webkit-appearance:;` to override this. And `-webkit-center` isn't a valid value for `text-align` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this won't work using `text-align: center` on select input. You can hide the original select input element and display the selected result using `div` of `span` or other html tag. Of course, you also need the help of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `text-align-last:center;` in google chrome. But this will not work in safari. You will have to use javascript or if values are defined you can use padding and can be calculated based on text length.